# Error Handling doesn't handle

Tags: excel, vba, object, error-handling

I have written an excel VBA script which refers to another open excel document for some of it's data. Recently it has come to my attention that if this secondary document is closed unexpectedly by the user, the primary script ceases to work. Obviously, I need to check to be sure it is open before I search it.

Below is the code I came up with to verify that the workbook is open. If it is, I format it. If it isn't, I open it (which triggers it's own formatting). The problem comes in because my error handler catches the "Object required" error number 424. I try to take care of that by instructing it to just resume next when this happens. Unfortunately it seems to want to pick case else rather than case 424 and stops the script.

```
On Error GoTo searchGridsError

GridName = Workbooks(SALTname).Sheets(2).Range("B3").value
If Verify.FirstOption.value = True Then
    Set Verify.groupGrid = Workbooks(GridName)
    If Verify.groupGrid Is Nothing Then
        Verify.checkForGrids
    Else
        formatWorkbook
    End If
End If
```

Below is my error handler:

```
searchGridsError:
Select Case Err
Case 18
Verify.clearData
Exit Function
Case 424
Resume Next
Case Else
MsgBox "An error has occurred while searching the customer number grid. Please try again or search manually."
Module1.ReportError Err.Number, Erl, Err.Description, "searchGrids", Verify.Address1Box & "," & Verify.Address2Box & "," & Verify.CityBox & "," & Verify.StateBox & "," & Verify.ZipBox & "," & Verify.ContractBox & "," & Verify.PBPBox & "," & Verify.CountyBox
Verify.clearData
Exit Function
End Select
End Function
```

Does anyone have any ideas about why this is happening? It has to be in the error handler but I have seen many, many examples that look just like mine.

Comment: In `Case 424` you opt to `Resume Next`, which likely sends it straight to `Case Else`. But hard to know. have you tried putting a code break on or before your `On Error` line and stepping through the code to see what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As guitarthrower stated in the comments, simply putting `Resume Next` in your error handling does not resume your macro back where the error occurred. To do that you would need to put another placeholder after your `On Error GoTo searchGridsError` line like `RestartHere:` where you want to jump back to and then replace `Resume Next` with:

```
On Error Resume Next
GoTo RestartHere
```

However, this will bypass your error handling once Error 424 is encountered, so you should be wary of how it is used.

Probably a better solution would be to put your error handling right in your code where you expect the error to occur. You can leave your code mostly as-is. However, right before the line that is throwing Error 424, you add `On Error Resume Next`. Then after the line in question, you add the following:

```
If Err.Number = 424 Then
    Err.Clear
End If
On Error GoTo searchGridsError
```

Comment: more eloquent than my comment :) + 1

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. It is actually even simpler - I think I just need to goto the restart point. I had no intention of changing my error handling to on error resume next, although it is an ah-ha moment to see that it works this way.